# Linear operator $(Af)(t) = \int_ 0^t e^{t-s}f(s)ds$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X := C[0,1]$ be a Banach space equibed with the norm $||f|| = max_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |f(t)|$.
Define a linear operator $A : C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ by
$(Af)(t) = \int_ 0^t e^{t-s}f(s)ds$.

I need to prove certain propertities concerning this linear operator. First of all I need to show that $A \in B(X)$ which to my understanding means that I have to show that the operator A is bounded. To show this I think I should calculate $||Af||$ and show that $||Af|| \leq C||f||$ always. Problem is that I don't quite know how would I do this. So far I have gotten $||Af|| = max_ {0 \leq t \leq 1} | \int_ 0^t e^{t-s}f(s)ds|$.

After this I need to show that A is injective and not surjective. Injectivity is easy to show by using derivative but the surjectivity is again causing me some problems.

This was an exercise in an old exam and when I took it I couldn't do it. Now I would like to know how this should be done seeing as it does not seem to be too complicated.

Comment: Surjectivity seems quite wrong.

Comment: Oh yes in fact in the exercise it was asked to show that A is injective and NOT surjective. Somehow I missed the word 'not' when reading the question. Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: (1) For the norm inequality, note that for $t \in [0,1]\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$ we have $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$
$$ \abs{(Af)(t)} \le \int_0^t \abs{f(t)}\, \exp(t-s)\, ds \le \norm f \int_0^t \exp(t-s)\, ds $$
(2) As you say, injectivity follow from noting that $Af$ is always differentiable with 
$$ (Af)'(t) = f(t) + Af(t). $$

(3) Noting that $Af$ is always differentiable, can $A$ be onto $C([0,1])$, noting that there are quite many non-differentiable continuous functions?

Comment: Ok this helped alot, thank you for your help. By the way, I was wondering about the inverse of A. Seeing as it is injective but not surjective does it exist?