# Show the linear map $[Ax](t) = \int_{0}^{t}exp(t-s)x(s)ds$ is injective and not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

Good day. I'm interested in the following question:

> Consider the function space $V =$ {$x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}, x$ continuous} (with the usual way to add functions and
> multiply them by real numbers) and the linear map:
>
> $$ A : V \rightarrow V, [Ax](t) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds$$
>
> Prove or refute the following statements: i.) The map A is injective
> ii.) The map A is surjective

I've been provided with answers for this question, and I'm trying to understand them:

> i.) True. As A is linear, it is sufficient to show that ker A =
> {$0$}. Let's assume that Ax = $0$, that is, for all t:
>
> $$\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = 0$$
>
> Let $$y(t) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds$$ So $$y'(t) = x(t) +
> \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = x(t) - y(t)$$ Rearranging, we have $x(t)
>  = y'(t) - y(t)$. As $y(t) = 0$ for all t, this implies that $x(t) = 0$ such that $x$ is the zero vector in V. Hence, Ker A = {$0$} and A is
> injective.

> ii.) False. The function $y(t) = 1$ (a constant function) is not in
> Im A. Trying to find a continuous $x$ with
> $$\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = 1$$ for all t, we notice that the
> left-hand side must be equal to $0$ as t = $0$, but the right-hand side
> equals 1. Thus, no $x \in V$ exists with $Ax = y$, such that A is not
> surjective.

I can follow most of the reasoning for the answer to the first part, except for why $$y'(t) = x(t) + \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = x(t) - y(t)$$

I did see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525785/linear-operator-aft-int-0t-et-sfsds) post which, coincidentally enough, refers to the same linear map. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/525789/1120880) answer, martini says

> $(Af)′(t)=f(t)+Af(t)$

but I don't know why this is the case.

In terms of the second part, it intuitively makes sense to me why $$\int_{0}^{0}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = 0$$ As $$\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx = 0$$ But I don't understand why $$\int_{0}^{0}e^{(t-s)}x(s)ds = 0$$ Proves the linear map is not surjective or proves why there is no solution to $y(t) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $t$,
$$
(Ax)(t) = e^t \int_0^t e^{-s}x(s)ds.
$$
Differentiating both sides (using the product rule and the FTC on the right) we get that
$$
(Ax)'(t) = e^te^{-t}x(t) + e^t \int_0^t e^{-s}x(s)ds = x(t)+(Ax)(t).
$$
So, the first solution should said that $y'(t)$ is $x(t)+y(t)$, not $x(t)-y(t)$.

---

For the second question, the equality
$$
(Ax)(0) = 0
$$
implies that, no matter what $x$ we choose, $Ax$ is not equal to the constant function with value $1$; that is, it is not true that $(Ax)(t)=1$ *for all* $t$.

Comment: This type of answer was exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you for your help, kind stranger! =)